# How to read a shortcut file (and get its target) in a Windows RT metro app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

1. I have accessed normal files and folders, but unable to read the target value from a shortcut file. Any idea how to read a shortcut file in WinRT?
2. My actual requirement is to find the most recently used/opened files in the system This info was previously available through Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a file AppData\Local\recently-used.xbel which contains this information on Win8. Parsing it should be easy, but the problem will probably be to get access to this file as it isn't in the folders that can be accessed via any manifest declaration. Also the AppData folder is hidden, making it inaccessible via the FileOpenPicker.

My guess would be that this is an intentional change by Microsoft since it is no business of a sandboxed app, which documents were used by other apps. If you want to open files that were recently opened by your app, you can roll your own "recently changed" implementation. Which should be easy because you have to save their token to the FutureAccessList anyhow.